# Find value in a column which has most of the listed values in either of two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to find the `ID` which has most of the user given values. A small data set is shared below:

```
ID  Val1    Val2    Time
1   A         B     12:00
1   A         C     13:10
1   C         D     13:19
2   L         O     14:00
2   A         C     15:00
2   A         M     15:00
3   P         J     16:00
```

Search vector:

```
Vc = c("A","B","C","I","T")
```

The search vector may be present in both `Val1` or `Val2`. The result I am looking for is:

```
ID  Match
1   3
2   2
```

Answer (score 1):

(Assumption: the values in `Vc`are unique.)
With `data.table`:

```
library("data.table")
setDT(D)
D[, sum(Vc %in% c(Val1, Val2)), ID]
D[, sum(Vc %in% c(Val1, Val2)), ID][V1>0] # without zero counts
```

alternative code (but the same logic):

```
D[, sum(unique(c(Val1, Val2)) %in% Vc), ID][V1>0]
```

data:

```
D <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text=
"ID  Val1    Val2    Time
1   A         B     12:00
1   A         C     13:10
1   C         D     13:19
2   L         O     14:00
2   A         C     15:00
2   A         M     15:00
3   P         J     16:00")
Vc = c("A", "B", "C", "I", "T")
```

Here is another solution with `data.table`:

```
library("data.table")

D <- fread(
"ID  Val1    Val2    Time
1   A         B     12:00
1   A         C     13:10
1   C         D     13:19
2   L         O     14:00
2   A         C     15:00
2   A         M     15:00
3   P         J     16:00")
Vc <- data.table(V1=c("A", "B", "C", "I", "T"))

D[, .(c(Val1, Val2), ID)][Vc, on="V1", length(unique(V1)), ID]
D[, .(c(Val1, Val2), ID)][Vc, on="V1", length(unique(V1)), ID, nomatch=0] # without the NA
```

Comment: The search vector may have values both in Val1 and in Val2

Comment: 1st solution doesn't include `Val2` and gives odd result even when one of the `Val1` is replaced by `Val2`

Comment: As far as I understand it does provide the desired result (minus the filter on zero counts)

Answer (score 0):

```
D <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text=
"ID  Val1    Val2    Time
1   A         B     12:00
1   A         C     13:10
1   C         D     13:19
2   L         O     14:00
2   A         C     15:00
2   A         M     15:00
3   P         J     16:00")
Vc = c("A", "B", "C", "I", "T")   

 D %>% 
      group_by(ID) %>% 
      summarize(Match = sum(unique((Val1 %in% Vc),(Val2 %in% Vc)))) %>% 
      filter(Match > 0)
```

Comment: `summarize(Match = sum(unique(c(Val1,Val2)) %in% Vc)` will avoid the redundancy

Comment: Or `summarize(Match = sum(Vc %in% c(Val1,Val2)))` actually to be even shorter, if `Vc` contains unique values

Comment: Please put the needed packages in: `library(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You could also transform your dataframe to long format and do the calculations:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  gather(k, v, Val1:Val2) %>% 
  distinct(ID, v) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarize(Match = sum(v %in% Vc)) %>% 
  filter(Match > 0)
```

The result:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     ID Match
  <int> <int>
1     1     3
2     2     2
```